# Limiting streaming service bandwidth speeds

Tags: networking, firewall

I'm trying to find a way to limit the bandwidth that Netflix and other streaming services can get. I've looked into qos but haven't found anything that talks about per website. I have found settings that can limit my whole browser or a device.

I have windows 10 professional using a edgerouter x, I currently am using the smart queue which works pretty dang well. Removes the bufferbloat but I'm finding netflix and the other types of streaming services like amazon prime video, hulu +live TV, and thecw.com take the entire connection that I have which is 12mbps download. Looking at the "required" data usage for these services to achieve either 480p 1080p or 4k doesn't exceed 4mbps. The current smart queue is working but soon I'm in need of an advanced queue and I'm not finding how to simulate a smart queue while using the advanced queues of the router.

I was hoping to find a way to instead of saying this is my queue for subnet xxx or IP xxx I wanted to say netflix go this fast, amazon is allowed this high and so on.

Without any qos on the network one user of Netflix or any other streaming service eats all 12mbps and when second user comes on they get almost 0 bandwidth.

With smart queue the services still eat the whole 12mbps until another device comes online needing bandwidth and it adjusts to allow both streams, the problem is I can't set a priority using the smart queue method for a server needed higher priority.

Comment: If we don't know your system configuration there is no way to help you.

Comment: They self limit to give you the best quality they can, while still sharing bandwidth nicely. But a lot of routers have terrible queue management that screws it up (this is called bufferbloat). If your internet connection gets laggy when someone is streaming, it most likely means you need a router that does Smart Queue Management (SQM). Run http://dslreports.com/speedtest from a desktop of laptop web browser to check your bufferbloat grade.

Comment: I don't know what you've been looking at but even HD quality already exceeds 4 mbps according to [netflix](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/306) for their service. Other services probably do the same, especially at 4k.

Comment: Then that reinforces my need for finding a solution. If it's not qos'd properly then 1-2 sessions would take all the bandwidth as it always defaults to highest quality and takes all available bandwidth. Netflix seems to be the only service that let's you choose streaming quality that I can find. Hulus service quality doesnt on desktops, work confirmed by hulu, and amazon prime and cwtv.com I dont see options at all.